# Como enviar a metodo "the_field" (plugin ACF) un valor dinámico desde un select HTML en Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

En mi template estoy trabajando con el archivo single.php donde creo el select.

```
 <div class="select-post">
   <label>Elige una unidad </label>
     <?php
       $lastposts = get_posts( array(
         'cat' => $term->term_id,
       ));
     ?>
     <select id="meal" name="meal" class="meal" onchange="infodeptos($(this).val());">
        <?php
          foreach ($lastposts as $posts) {
            echo '<option value="'.$posts->ID.'">'.$posts->post_title.'</option>';
            }
          ?>
    </select>
 </div>

 <div id="box-info">
   <?php include('content.php');?>
 </div>
```

al cambiar el valor del select lo mando al javaScript

```
function infodeptos(id) {
  var parametros = {
    "id" : id
  };

  $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   '/wp-content/themes/brotec-wp/content.php',
        type:  'post',
        success:  function (response) { 
            console.log(response);

            // $("#respuesta").html(response);
        }
  });
}
```

y por último el archivo content.php donde quiero guardar en la variable $post_id el valor del select enviado desde el js y pasarlo al HTML para que así los datos se muestren en la vista. Pero resulta que no logro capturar el valor desde el js en el PHP al imprimir la variable siempre es null y me manda el siguiente error al success del js: **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /wp-content/themes/brotec-wp/content.php on line **11**
, pero si le cargo manualmente la variable $post_id = 1; al cargar el sitio web me carga los datos correctamente.

Probe varias formas y no encuentro como capturarlo y pasarlo al HTML, help my!!.

```
<?php 
  $post_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
?>
<div class="info" id="info">
  <ul>
    <?php if(get_field('dormitorios',$post_id)): ?>
      <li class="dormitorio"><?php the_field('dormitorios',$post_id); ?> dormitorios</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_field('banos',$post_id)): ?>
    <li class="banos"><?php the_field('banos',$post_id); ?> baños</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li class="sup-total"><strong>Sub. Total <br /><?php the_field('sub_total',$post_id); ?></strong></li>
    <li class="item">Depto <br /><?php the_field('depto',$post_id); ?></li>
    <li class="item">Terraza <br /><?php the_field('terraza',$post_id); ?></li>
    <li class="sup-util"><strong>Sup.Útil <br /><?php the_field('sup_util',$post_id); ?></strong></li>
    <li class="item">Depto <br /><?php the_field('depto2',$post_id); ?></li>
    <li class="item">Terraza<br /><?php the_field('terraza2',$post_id); ?></li>
    <li class="orientacion">Orientacion: <?php the_field('orientacion',$post_id); ?></li>
    <li class="entrega">Entrega segundo semestre <?php the_field('entrega',$post_id); ?></li>
 </ul>
 <a class="cotizar" href="#">COTIZAR</a>
</div>
```

Formulario con datos cargados de manera estática

[image: Formulario con datos cargados de manera estática]

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto:

En wordpress en el archivo function.php cree una funcion donde cree las variables y cargue los get_field necesarios con su id el nombre de cada campo creado con el plugins Advanced Custom Fields, despues pase los datos al ajax y de ahi al HTML.

archivo function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_detalles', 'getDetalles');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_detalles', 'getDetalles');

function getDetalles (){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $dormitorios = $_POST['dormitorios'];
    $banos = $_POST['banos'];

    $campo1 = get_field($dormitorios, $id);
    $campo2 = get_field($banos, $id);
    echo json_encode([
        'respuesta1' => $campo1,
        'respuesta2' => $campo2,
    ]);
    exit;
}
```

archivo JS

```
function infodeptos(id) {

    var parametros = {
        "id" : id,
        "dormitorios": "dormitorios",
        "banos": "banos",
    };
    $.ajax({
      type:  "post", 
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_detalles",
      data:  parametros,
      success:  function (data) {
        $('.dormitorio').html(data.respuesta1+" Dormitorios");
        $('.banos').html(data.respuesta2+" Baños");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        // Error handling
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

}

HTML

```
<div id="box-info">
  <div class="info" id="info">
     <ul>
       <li class="dormitorio">Dormitorios</li>
       <li class="banos">baños</li>
     </ul>
     <a class="cotizar" href="#">COTIZAR</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```